# Dirichlet Spectrum of Laplacian In 2D Annulus

Tags: spectral-theory, laplacian

What are the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the Euclidean Laplacian for the annulus in 2D bound by radii r_1 < 1 < r_2 if we consider zero Dirichlet boundary conditions?  I’m aware that this is something to derive by separation of variables in polar coordinates but I would very much appreciate a reference or suggestions!